# Cannot retrieve data which includes specific symbols in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I try to use Kibana to retrive the comment data which includes some specific symbols like `？`and `。` They are not general symbols.

I try to use escape character `\` for them, the KQL is like `comment:\？`or `comment:\\?`, but it doesn't work, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a sample doc and let ES auto-generate the mapping for you,

```
POST comments/_doc
{
  "comment": "？"
}
```

running

```
GET comments/_mapping
```

will get you

```
"comment":{
  "type":"text",
  "fields":{
    "keyword":{
      "type":"keyword",
      "ignore_above":256
    }
  }
}
```

Now, the `text` type's [analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer.html) is usually [`standard`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#text-params) by default.

When we attempt to see how our non-standard chars got analyzed

```
GET comments/_analyze
{
  "text": "？",
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

the result is

```
{
  "tokens" : [ ]
}
```

meaning we cannot search for its contents using the standard-analyzed `text` field but need to

1. either define a different default analyzer
2. or define this analyzer in one of the comment's `fields`

Going with the 2nd approach (since it's good practice to keep differently-analyzed fields separate),

```
PUT comments2
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "comment": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "whitespace_analyzed": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "whitespace"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST comments2/_doc
{
  "comment": "？"
}
```

After verifying

```
GET comments2/_analyze
{
  "text": "？",
  "analyzer": "whitespace"
}
```

we can do the following in KQL

```
comment.whitespace_analyzed:"？"
```

*Note that there are a bunch of [built-in analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html) to choose from but you're more than welcome to create your own.*